# Merge lines that are approximately collinear and close together into one line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I used the Line Segment detection of OpenCV to detect lines, then I separated them into two separate parts, one list containing only horizontal lines and one list containing only vertical lines.

The next task is that I want to merge close lines into a single line, provided that the lines are not too far apart. The image below is an illustration of my desired result.[image]

I tried sorting by the y-axis and grouped the lines according to my naive understanding, and a bug appeared.

For example, the lines we see in the image from left to right are 1 2 3 4 5 6. After sorting again and taking the algorithm to connect the lines I proposed, the elements in the sort will be 1 3 4 2 5 6. Thus, it will not be able to connect in sequence.
Here is my code :

```
def process_lines(lines, pixel_threshold=10):
    sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line[1])
    group_list = []

    start_line = sorted_lines[0]

    for i in range(1,len(sorted_lines)):
        x1_start, y1_start, x2_start, y2_start, _ = start_line
        x1_temp, y1_temp, x2_temp, y2_temp, _ = sorted_lines[i]

        # Check conditions for merging lines
        if abs(x2_start - x1_temp) <= pixel_threshold and abs(y2_start - y1_temp) <= pixel_threshold:
            # Merge lines
            start_line = (x1_start, y1_start, x2_temp, y2_temp, _)
        else:
            group_list.append(start_line)
            start_line = sorted_lines[i]

    group_list.append(start_line)

    return group_list

grouped_horizontal_lines = process_lines(filtered_horizontal_lines)
print(len(grouped_horizontal_lines))
Test_group_line = np.ones_like(white_background_horizontal) * 0

for group in grouped_horizontal_lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2, _ = map(int, group)
    cv2.line(Test_group_line, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 3)
```

I am looking forward to your help, and I sincerely thank you.

Comment: Just use a horizontal morphology close kernel large enough to fill the gaps